# heroku complaining about my public key created by ssh-keygen2

Tags: heroku, ssh-keys

I am trying to access my heroku app from work (windows machine).

I installed cygwin on the machine and generated ssh-key as well. However, I get the below error:

> C:>heroku keys:add
>   "C:\cygwin\home\4541450\mycoolemail@email.com"
>   Uploading ssh public key
>   C:\cygwin\home\4541450\mycoolemail@email.com
>   Enter your Heroku credentials. Email:
>   mycoolemail@email.com Password:
>   Uploading ssh public key
>   C:\cygwin\home\c54550\mycoolemail@email.com
>   !   **Contents Invalid public key /
>   Contents Invalid public key /
>   Fingerprint can 't be blank**

I generated the ssh key with the command below.

> ssh-keygen2 "mycoolemail@email.com" -t
>   rsa

ssh-keygen is not available with this cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

the "C:\cygwin\home\4541450\mycoolemail@email.com" should be your public key, not the private one

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811387/has-anyone-successfully-deployed-on-heroku-from-a-windows-platform) is helpful. It's my setup for deploying to Heroku from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a passphrase on the key? Mine didn't work until I generated one with a passphrase.