# Has anyone successfully deployed on heroku from a windows platform?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ssh-keys

I've been reading all kinds of tutorials on how to deploy rails apps on heroku from windows.

I've tried installing git, heroku gem, generating ssh keys and setting paths and everything...

I get either public key error (without putty) or fatal no auth found (with putty)...

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with Heroku. You just need to fix your SSH keypair issues.

Comment: yes, that seems to be the real problem indeed

Comment: I have exactly the same question (mostly. I believe stuff can be deployed, but I'm not convinced one can even complete the tutorial using windows). I've been through four years of posts and workarounds trying to get through the tutorial alone. So far I've only heard people entirely giving up on making the whole setup work on windows. I would really like to talk with someone who managed to get it working on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some setup problems -- indeed related to SSH keys -- I've successfully developed Rails/Sinatra applications on Windows and deployed those to Heroku. It works fine.

Generating the keys was a challenge -- I didn't keep notes, but I think I generated the keys with the Git GUI in which you can create a OpenSSH key. That key file is stored in `~/.ssh` (so within `C:\Documents and Settings\<account>\.ssh`) as `id_rsa` with an accompanying `id_rsa.pub`. Since I wanted a seperate key for use in Heroku, I've renamed both files of the key pair to `id_heroku` / `id_heroku.pub`.

Finally, in the same folder, I've created a file `config`. That file contains

```
Host heroku.com
Hostname heroku.com
Port 22
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_heroku
TCPKeepAlive yes
User user@example.com
```

Comment: hmm, interesting, I shall give it another try

Comment: Oh, and that part `User user@example.com` should be your Heroku account name (= email address). I've got another folder `~/.heroku` that has a file `credentials`. That file contains two lines: the account name = email address, and your password.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you may utilize puTTYgen.exe , and paste the OpenSSH public key into a mykey.pub file, and uploading that with heroku keys:add c:\mykey.pub